# Syntax Error php

Tags: php

Глупая ошибка, не понимаю что не так в коде

```
function getCountry($link){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  `countries` LIMIT 0 , 30";
    $results = Array();
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if($result){ 
        foreach ($result as $key => $countries){
            array_push($results, $countries)
        }   
        return $results;                            
    }

}
```

Ошибка в строке перед return, что не так?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in Z:\home\localhost\www\...\queries.php on line 10
```

Comment: Точка с запятой?

Comment: `return $link->query("SELECT * FROM  countries LIMIT 0 , 30")->fetch_all();`

Comment: После array_push($results, $countries) надо поставить точку с запятой. Учите синтаксис, или займитесь чем-то другим.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```html
function getCountry($link){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM  `countries` LIMIT 0 , 30";
    $results = Array();
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if($result){ 
        foreach ($result as $key => $countries){
            array_push($results, $countries); // здесь не хватало точки с запятой
        }   
        return $results;                            
    }

}
```

Comment: На вопросы, вызванные синтаксической ошибкой, не нужно отвечать. Надо голоосовать за их закрытие